# exit all supervisord processes if one exited

Tags: docker, supervisord

I have a docker image where I wish:
- to run a passenger server and another daemon for monitoring the passenger server.
- the container to exit as soon as either one of these 2 processes exit even once.
- direct all logs to stdout

In config file, I have put an event listener (Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/760726/how-to-exit-all-supervisor-processes-if-one-exited-with-0-result/762406#762406) that captures some events for passenger_monit program and executes a script tt.sh.

I can see 1 extra instance of passenger_monit program being spawned and reaching FATAL state after a few tries. The other passenger_monit and passenger_server are fine. The other passenger_monit's events don't reach the eventlistener.

These are the scripts which are not working as expected:

This is the `supervisord.conf`

```
[supervisord]

nodaemon=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

[unix_http_server]
file=%(here)s/supervisor.sock

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix://%(here)s/supervisor.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:passenger_monit]

command=./script/passenger_monit.sh
process_name=passenger_monit
startretries=999
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=true
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
numprocs=1

[program:passenger_server]

command=passenger start
startretries=999
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=true
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
numprocs=1

[eventlistener:passenger_monit_exit]
command=./tt.sh
process_name=passenger_monit
events=PROCESS_STATE_STARTING,PROCESS_STATE_EXITED,PROCESS_STATE_FATAL
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

This is the `./script/passenger_monit.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

cd /passenger/newrelic_passenger_plugin/

# if exec is not put, then this process is not killed when supervisord exits
exec ./newrelic_passenger_agent

set +x
```

This is `tt.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "in tt!"
```

This is the command I run:

```
docker exec -it -u deploy 56bbbbe4352b  supervisord
```

This is the output I get:

```
2016-08-26 19:47:29,369 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-08-26 19:47:29,369 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-08-26 19:47:29,370 INFO supervisord started with pid 2446
2016-08-26 19:47:30,374 INFO spawned: 'passenger_monit' with pid 2452
2016-08-26 19:47:30,377 INFO spawned: 'passenger_server' with pid 2453
in tt!
2016-08-26 19:47:30,392 INFO exited: passenger_monit (exit status 0; not expected)
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /home/deploy/abc/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /home/deploy/abc/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/troubleshooting/
===============================================================================
2016-08-26 19:47:31,565 INFO spawned: 'passenger_monit' with pid 2494
2016-08-26 19:47:31,566 INFO success: passenger_server entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
in tt!
2016-08-26 19:47:31,571 INFO exited: passenger_monit (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-08-26 19:47:33,576 INFO spawned: 'passenger_monit' with pid 2498
in tt!
2016-08-26 19:47:33,583 INFO exited: passenger_monit (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-08-26 19:47:36,588 INFO spawned: 'passenger_monit' with pid 2499
in tt!
2016-08-26 19:47:36,595 INFO exited: passenger_monit (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-08-26 19:47:37,597 INFO gave up: passenger_monit entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly


^C2016-08-26 19:47:47,730 WARN received SIGINT indicating exit request
2016-08-26 19:47:47,735 INFO waiting for passenger_server to die
Stopping web server... done
2016-08-26 19:47:47,839 INFO stopped: passenger_server (exit status 2)
```

This is the output for `supervisorctl status`

```
passenger_monit                  STOPPED    Not started
passenger_monit_exit:passenger_monit FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
passenger_server                 RUNNING    pid 2453, uptime 0:00:14
```

Output of `supervisord -v`

```
3.0b2
```

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://serverfault.com/q/799327/351549)

Answer (score 4):

The following should work. Notice the 10 second script will be killed after 5 seconds.

```
[supervisord]
loglevel=warn
nodaemon=true

[program:hello]
command=bash -c "echo waiting 5 seconds . . . && sleep 5"
autorestart=false
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:world]
command=bash -c "echo waiting 10 seconds . . . && sleep 10"
autorestart=false
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

[eventlistener:processes]
command=bash -c "echo READY && read line && kill -SIGQUIT $PPID"
events=PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED,PROCESS_STATE_EXITED,PROCESS_STATE_FATAL
```

Comment: Super answer. Works great!